# Explode effect jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-effects

I have a banner which need to be appear by explode effect in jquery.

html:

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="click-for-more">Click For More!</div>
</div>
<div class="mosaic">
<div class="close-btn">X</div>
<img src="1280x1024(image).jpg">
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".click-for-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         $('.mosaic').show("explode", { pieces: 64 }, 2000);
    });

$(".close-btn").click(function(){
         $('.mosaic').hide("explode", { pieces: 64 }, 2000); 
    });
});
```

however, the effect is not working but lagging before it appear. Why is it happened? am i doing anything wrong in the code?

Comment: have you loaded `jQuery.ui.js`..?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

Comment: Seems to be working fine here.. http://jsfiddle.net/WXENN/

Comment: Ya I load the jquery.ui.js already. I was doing this effect on an image, is there anything stop the effect from happening? it seem run the jquery but the effect is lagged.

Comment: Will it because the size of the display image is too big????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/RvCS6/

**JS:-**

```
$(".click-for-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.mosaic').show("explode", { pieces: 64 }, 2000);
    });

$(".close-btn").click(function(){
        $('.mosaic').hide("explode", { pieces: 64 }, 2000); 
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for that I cant see any different the code, can you spot it out where u change the code and why? Thanks!

Comment: @youaremysunshine - Have you included jquery UI plugin also?

Comment: yup I included jquery-ui.css, jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-ui.js, and jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: ya i added, but still same problem. Actually I notice that the effect is actually works, but it didnt showed up and it only show some lagging on screen and then show my image.

Comment: Hi Wiz Kids thanks, I found that the it is the css margin problem and i put another div to solve it! Thanks anyway